# Summoning a mob on fire

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've recently discovered a fun thing if a spider was on fire: the size of the fire would be twice the size of a normal one. So then, with commands, I summoned invisible spider (though their eyes are still visible) and then the effect was great. But there was a problem: I couldn't summon a spider ON FIRE, and I had to push them into one. So my question is:

How can I summon a spider that is on fire?

PS: For some more information, this is what I wrote:

> /summon Spider {ActiveEffects:[{id:14,Duration:99999},{id:12,duration:99999}],Fire:99999}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Fire:` is a short tag, and 99999 is an invalid value. Try 32767, instead.

Comment: Thank for this, but you may better have post this as a comment, because it so not solve my question; it is to summon a mob that IS on fire. :)

Comment: @Kimatuy It does answer your question. You were originally using a value that overflowed to a negative value, meaning the entity wasn't on fire. By changing it to be within range (AKA 32767), the spider *will* be on fire.

Answer (score 0):

This summoned a spider on fire:

> /summon Spider ~ ~1 ~ {Fire: 1000, damage: 10, Motion:[0, 0, 0]}

I converted it from a flaming arrow summon command